# Why is opendaylight not compiling

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

I want to use opendaylight but I have problem compiling it. I am trying to solve this problem but I do not know what should I do.

Why is opendaylight not compiling:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.26.2:docs (default) on project networkconfig.neutron.northbound: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.26.2:docs failed: A required class was missing while executing org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.26.2:docs: com/sun/mirror/apt/AnnotationProcessorFactory
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.26.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/maven-enunciate-plugin/1.26.2/maven-enunciate-plugin-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/mahdi/Downloads/opendaylights/opendaylight/commons/logback_settings/target/commons.logback_settings-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/maven-enunciate-slim-plugin/1.26.2/maven-enunciate-slim-plugin-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-digest/1.0/plexus-digest-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/enforcer/enforcer-api/1.0/enforcer-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/root/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0/maven-filtering-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.12/plexus-interpolation-1.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-build-api/0.0.4/plexus-build-api-0.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-core/1.26.2/enunciate-core-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-core-rt/1.26.2/enunciate-core-rt-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-core-annotations/1.26.2/enunciate-core-annotations-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.3/servlet-api-2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/root/.m2/repository/net/sf/apt-jelly/apt-jelly-freemarker/2.15/apt-jelly-freemarker-2.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/root/.m2/repository/net/sf/apt-jelly/apt-jelly-core/2.15/apt-jelly-core-2.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.14/freemarker-2.3.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/2.1/commons-digester-2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/../lib/tools.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-top/1.26.2/enunciate-top-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-jaxws-support/1.26.2/enunciate-jaxws-support-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-jaxws-ri/1.26.2/enunciate-jaxws-ri-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-docs/1.26.2/enunciate-docs-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.3/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.3/jackson-core-asl-1.9.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/jdom/jdom/1.1.2/jdom-1.1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-jersey/1.26.2/enunciate-jersey-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-jersey-rt/1.26.2/enunciate-jersey-rt-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.3/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.9.3/jackson-xc-1.9.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.11/jersey-server-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/root/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.11/jersey-core-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-servlet/1.11/jersey-servlet-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.4/mail-1.4.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/root/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3/jaxb-impl-2.2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-xml/1.26.2/enunciate-xml-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-java-client/1.26.2/enunciate-java-client-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-c/1.26.2/enunciate-c-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-obj-c/1.26.2/enunciate-obj-c-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-csharp/1.26.2/enunciate-csharp-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/enunciate/enunciate-ruby/1.26.2/enunciate-ruby-1.26.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>org.opendaylight.controller:networkconfig.neutron.implementation:0.4.1-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessorFactory
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :networkconfig.neutron.northbound
```

what can i do about this problem.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to clarify which ODL project you’re trying to compile, and how you’re trying to compile it? The error you’re getting has been fixed for a long time (since at least 2015) — you should be pulling in version 1.31 of the Enunciate Maven plugin.

Comment: Note `org.opendaylight.controller:networkconfig.neutron.implementation:0.4.1-SNAPSHOT`.. I guess this is either some internal code (not a public ODL FLOSS project) or a VERY (more than 3 years) old ODL code base ("neutron" has been in "controller" for a long time now)... as such, it may be difficult to offer more support. The suggestion from @StephenKitt to upgrade the Enunciate Maven plugin yourself may help you. Best of luck

Comment: I think you meant - "neutron" hasn't been in "controller..." -   probably since the helium release.